# Mathematica RegionPlot on the surface of the unit sphere?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I am using `RegionPlot3D` in Mathematica to visualise some inequalities.  As the inequalities are homogeneous in the coordinates they are uniquely determined by their intersection with the unit sphere.  This gives some two-dimensional regions *on the surface of the sphere* which I would like to plot.  My question is **how?**

If requested I would be more than happy to provide some Mathematica code; although I believe that the answer should be independent on the details of the regions I'm trying to plot.

Thanks in advance!

**Update**: In case anyone is interested, I have recently finished a paper in which I used Sasha's answer below in order to make some plots.  The paper is [Symmetric M-theory backgrounds](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4967) and was arXived last week.  It contains plots such as this one:

[image: F-moduli space for a symmetric M-theory background]

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi José. Welcome to stackoverflow, it's nice to see you over here (and thanks for all of the nice physics notes).

Comment: Many thanks, Simon!  I'm impressed by the speed this question was answered.  It's almost as fast as in MathOverflow :)

Comment: @Jose Welcome to stackoverflow. Please remember to accept one of the answers that solved your problem. The [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has some useful information.

Comment: Dear Sasha, Thanks.  I am quite familiar with the software from my involvement in MathOverflow.  I tend to wait a little to accept an answer to ensure I accept the best one.  I have just been playing with the different answers and I like yours the best, hence I've accepted that.  Cheers, José

Comment: @José: Only almost as fast... I guess we'll have to try harder! My excuses are that the Mathematica community here is still quite small and that I was watching West Wing whilst writing my solution (Otherwise I might have had the clarity of mind to remember `RegionFunction`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please look into [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegionFunction.html). You can use your inequalities verbatim in it inside [`ParametricPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html).

```
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[th] Cos[ph], Sin[th] Sin[ph], 
    Cos[th]}, {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, And[x^3 < x y z + z^3, y^2 z < y^3 + x z^2]], 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Sphere[]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 The sphere transparency and mesh really help visualize the region.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the simplest idea I could come up with (thanks to [belisarius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353410/belisarius) for [some of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603281/how-do-you-get-custom-3d-graphics-to-display-properly-in-mathematica/5603326#5603326)).

- Project the inequalities onto the sphere using spherical coordinates (with θ=q, φ=f).
- Plot these as a flat region plot.
- Then plot this as a texture the sphere.

Here's a couple of homogeneous inequalities of order 3

```
ineq = {x^3 < x y^2, y^2 z > x z^2};

coords = {x -> r Sin[q] Cos[f], y -> r Sin[q] Sin[f], z -> r Cos[q]}/.r -> 1

region = RegionPlot[ineq /. coords, {q, 0, Pi}, {f, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Frame -> None, ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image: flat region]

```
ParametricPlot3D[coords[[All, 2]], {q, 0, Pi}, {f, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Mesh -> None, TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &), 
 PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[region, ImageSize -> 1000]]]
```

[image: animation]

Comment: Thanks.  I had thought of projecting to the plane and using `RegionPlot` but had no idea how to map it back to the sphere.  I had no idea about `Texture` and from the name I would never have guessed that this is what I was looking for!

Comment: +1 for remembering to turn off the frame and plot range and image padding.

Answer (score 6):

Simon beat me to the punch but here's a similar idea, based on lower level graphics.  I deal with linear, homogeneous inequalities of the form Ax>0.

```
A = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {8, 3}];
eqs = And @@ Thread[
    A.{Sin[phi] Cos[th], Sin[phi] Sin[th], Cos[phi]} >
        Table[0, {Length[A]}]];
twoDPic = RegionPlot[eqs,
    {phi, 0, Pi}, {th, 0, 2 Pi}];
pts2D = twoDPic[[1, 1]];
spherePt[{phi_, th_}] := {Sin[phi] Cos[th], Sin[phi] Sin[th], 
    Cos[phi]};
rpSphere = Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[spherePt /@ pts2D,
   twoDPic[[1, 2]]]]
```

Let's compare it against a `RegionPlot3D`.

```
rp3D = RegionPlot3D[And @@ Thread[A.{x, y, z} >
      Table[0, {Length[A]}]],
 {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.2]];
Show[{rp3D, rpSphere}, PlotRange -> 1.4]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SphericalPlot3D[0.6, {\[Phi], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 RegionFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   PolyhedronData["Cube", "RegionFunction"][x, y, z]], Mesh -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Opacity[0.9]}]
```