# Texturing a sphere primitive

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm using Mathematica 8 and I am struggling with texturing. Although texturing of polyhedral objects has proved to be relatively simple, I hit a problem trying to texture a sphere. In the documentation, the only way to texture a sphere shown is using `SphericalPlot3D`, which, IMHO, is a kludgey solution, especially since I'm trying to perform operations (e.g.: translation) on the sphere. *In toto*, my question is: is there any way to texture a sphere primitive?

Comment: Related: [RegionPlot on the surface of the unit sphere?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5788842/616736) and [How do you get custom 3D graphics to display properly in Mathematica?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5603281/616736)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't texture a `Sphere` directly, but you could create a textured sphere using e.g. `SphericalPlot3D` and extract the first part to get a primitive which you can manipulate with `Translate`. For example

```
sphere = SphericalPlot3D[1, th, phi, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> 25,
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[1], Texture[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "GiraffeFur"}]]},
  TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, #5} &)][[1]];

Graphics3D[Translate[sphere, {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}}]]
```

[image: textured spheres]

Answer (score 6):

Something like this will be helpful :

[image]

[image]

```
sphere = SphericalPlot3D[1, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
                             TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({2 #5, 1 - 2 #4} &), 
                             PlotStyle -> { Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False,
                             Boxed -> False, Texture[texture]},     Mesh -> None][[1]];

F[k_] := Graphics3D[ Rotate[ sphere, k, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 0, 0}], Boxed -> False]
```

Now, we can animate a textured sphere rotating (around the vector `{2, 1, 6}` anchored at the point `{0,0,0}` ) :

```
Animate[F[k], {k, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: No, that's what I managed to do... I want to texture a Sphere *primitive*, as produced by the Sphere[] function.

Comment: Applying a texture to `Sphere[]` is not currently possible.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, you can also generate spheres with textures using `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
map = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
sphere = ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 
  0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &), 
Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[map]]]
```

[image: lenasphere]

If I understand correctly, Heike's answer shows that the first part of the result is a GraphicsComplex, which is a graphics primitive.