# Mathematica: 3D plots,prevent notebook jitter while rotating 3D image with mouse?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I noticed that if I rotates a 3D image using the mouse, there is a little jitter or shaking in the notebook interface itself as I rotate the image around with the mouse.

i.e. the frame where the 3D image itself is, does shift a little up and down the notebook.

I tried all the tricks I know to prevent this, from setting different ImagePadding, PlotRangePadding, ImageMargins, PlotRange, ContentSize and everything else but no luck.

Here is a small example, I just used RegionPlot3D as an example, but any 3D plot will do.

```
Manipulate[
      RegionPlot3D[True, 
                 {x,1,2},{y,1,2},{z,1,2},
                 AxesLabel-> label,
                 ImageSize->{340,450},
                 ImagePadding->10,
                 ImageMargins->10,
                 MeshStyle->Automatic,
                 PlotRangePadding->1,
                 AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},                   
                 PlotRange->{{0,2},{0,2},{0,2}},
                 Boxed->False],
     {n,0,ControlType->None},

 SynchronousUpdating->False,
 ContinuousAction->False
 ]
```

Now if you run the above, and using the mouse to rotate the little cube, you'll start noticing, once you release the mouse, that the notebook did jitter a little.  Feel free to try any other settings.

It is annoying, as I do not like this shaking effect. Makes me dizzy.

Any expert here might know if it is option setting that I am overlooking in the Plot command itself, or may be something else?  I'd like the plot frame and the notebook itself not to shake while I am rotating the image inside with the mouse. The problem again shows up when one release the mouse.

Mathematica 8.0.1 on windows 7.

thanks
--Nasser
ps. I tried to search if this was asked before, but did not spot something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
SphericalRegion -> True
```

Like in:

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot3D[True, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 1, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> label, SphericalRegion -> True, 
  ImageSize -> {340, 450}, ImagePadding -> 10, ImageMargins -> 10, 
  MeshStyle -> Automatic, PlotRangePadding -> 1, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0, 2}, {0, 2}}, 
  Boxed -> False], {n, 0, ControlType -> None}, 
 SynchronousUpdating -> False, ContinuousAction -> False]
```

From the Help:

```
With SphericalRegion->True, the image of a particular object remains consistent
in size, regardless of the orientation of the object.
```

**Edit**

Usage example in this answer: [How to create 2D (3D) animation in Wolfram Mathematica with the camera following the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376303/how-to-create-2d-3d-animation-in-wolfram-mathematica-with-the-camera-followed-t/5377618#5377618)

HTH!

Comment: Wow! I spend more than one hr trying everything I know. Never used this option before, thanks. +500

Comment: @Nasser Don't feel bad about that. I spent _much_ more than one hour when I tried to solve it. I needed to show an animated sequence and the "jitter" spoiled the animation ...

Comment: **belisarius, congratulations on Trusted User and 20,000 rep!**

Comment: @belisarius Congrats. You were at 13k7 when I started, so you're raking in rep at twice my rate. Are you glued to your computer?

Comment: @Sjoerd I do my work mostly in front of my laptop. I can't resist some questions :)